# how to represent a vector

Tags: vector-spaces, notation, vectors

I have to define a state space equation. there is a vector with 5 members as stats such that all states(members of the vector) are real numbers.

which notation is true for this case?

x=[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5] ∈ **R**

or

x=[x1,x2,x3,x4,x5] ∈ **R**^5

where ^ implies that the number 5 is the power of **R**

is both are correct. which one can I use to introduce my states?

Comment: The second one is the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the symbol $\mathbb R^n$ is used to denoted the vector space of $n$-dimensional real vectors. The symbol $\mathbb R$ is typically used to denote the set/field of real numbers, not a vector space.

With this in mind, both of the following notations would likely be readily understood:

$$\mathbf x  =\langle x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5 \rangle, \quad  \mathbf x \in \mathbb R^5$$
or 
$$\mathbf x  =\langle x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5 \rangle, \quad  x_i \in \mathbb R$$

Comment: Actually $\Bbb R$ _is_ a vector space...